# How do I escape the color character (:) inside the path, with React-Router V4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a urls that look something like this:

```
/foo/bar/main:home
/foo/bar/main:about_us
/foo/bar/main:contact_us
```

As you can see I have **:** in the url, that needs to be taken into consideration. What I want is to match component **Home** to `/foo/bar/main:home`, but any other path `/foo/bar/main:XXXXX` to match component **Default**.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
<Route path={'/foo/bar/main:home'} component={Home} />
<Route path={'/foo/bar/main:any'} component={Default} />
```

This matches the Home component all the time.

```
<Route path={'/foo/bar/main%3Ahome'} component={Home} />
<Route path={'/foo/bar/main:any'} component={Default} />
```

Now, Default is matched all the time. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React-router uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp). So to escape `:` I think this would work:

```
/foo/bar/main\\:contact_us
```