# How do you pass ":" in a URL without referring to a dynamic value in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component, connected-react-router

The problem is that when you want to introduce a dynamic value to a url is that you have to use ":" to refer to it.

For example, let's say I have a list with a lot of users and I add a button to get more info about them, and I want the URL to have the username of the user from where you're getting all the info. I would do something like this:

```
<Route path="/user/:name" component={Component} />
```

The problem occurs when, I have to, for some reason, put ":" in the URL without it meaning that I want that part of the URL to change. Basically to have a static URL with ":" in it.

Is this possible and if so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-router uses path-to-regexp. So you can escape it by using escape character.

```
<Route path="/user/\\:name" component={Component} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627129/how-do-i-escape-the-color-character-inside-the-path-with-react-router-v4) is what you're looking for.

```
/foo/bar/main\\:contact_us
```